# Navigation between one navigation container to another navigation container in react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native, navigation, stack, react-navigation

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';     
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';    
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';     
. . . .
```

all the screens were imported...

Log out of the profile screen and then navigate to the login screen.

my navigation file is...

```
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
export default Navigate = () => {

    function Editable() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
                <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} >
                    <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
                    <Stack.Screen name='Edit_profile' component={Edit_profile} />
                    <Stack.Screen name='MyComplaints' component={MyComplaints} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        )
    }

    function HomeScreen() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
                <BottomTab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{ keyboardHidesTabBar: true }}>
                    <BottomTab.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
                    <BottomTab.Screen name="Home2" component={Home2} />
                    <BottomTab.Screen name="Editable" component={Editable}/>
                    <BottomTab.Screen name="Feedback" component={Feedback}/>
                </BottomTab.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        )
    };

    return (
        <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} 
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
                <Stack.Screen name="App" component={App} />
                <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
};
```

I want to navigate from ProfileScreen to Login screen how can I do that?

Comment: 1. Import `import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core"` 2. Get the Navigation `const navigation = useNavigation()` 3. Handle this `navigation.navigate("Login")` may onPress

Answer (score 1):

Navigating between multiple navigation containers is impossible as they are independent from each other. You need to remove the nested `NavigationContainer` components.

There should be only one `NavigationContainer` at the root of your app.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/#wrapping-your-app-in-navigationcontainer

Answer (score 0):

You can create each `navigationRef` for each `NavigationContainer`. Then use this ref to navigate without the navigation prop or hook.

```js
// More info: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/


export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()

export function navigate(name: any, params?: any) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name as never, params as never)
  }
}
...
 <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} {...props}>
...
```